# How do i download image from database (Codeigniter 4)

Tags: download, controller, codeigniter-4

I am trying to download my uploaded files(image) by id from the database(phpmyadmin).
but there's an error said that variable $id is undefined.
this is the code i'm using, i got this code from some tutorial website.

```
public function download()
    {
        $berkas = new BerkasModel();
        $data = $berkas->find($id);
        return $this->response->download('uploads/berkas/' . $data->berkas, null);
    }
```

how can i fix this so i can download the uploaded files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the variable `$id` to the function.

Specific implementation depends on your setup. Looking at the small code fragment you posted (and the absence of any request variable extraction), pass it as function parameter:

`public function download($id)`.

Furthermore you need to adapt your `routes.php`and the calling `<a>` to reflect this change:

`routes.php`:

```php
$routes->get('download/(:segment)', [CLASSNAME::class, 'download']);
```

`<a href>`:

```html
<a href="YOUR_URL/download/<?= esc($id) ?>">Download</a>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you're fixing the routes also. really appreciate it.
just another question, you can ignore this...
for uploading image the rules i use is like this 'rules' => 'uploaded[berkas]|mime_in[berkas,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png]|max_size[berkas,2048]'. can i upload another format like pdf? example adding file/pdf to the rule i have here.

Comment: Just add `application/pdf` to your `mime_in[...]` field.

Answer (score 0):

You need `$id` in function `download()`

```
public function download($id)
{
    $berkas = new BerkasModel();
    $data = $berkas->find($id);
    return $this->response->download('uploads/berkas/' . $data->berkas, null);
}
```